# Sqlite3 with Python - Query from external file

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I would like to create my DB by an external file like:

```
database = "../data/cm4payroll.db"
query = "../data/emdb.sql"
# Datenbankverbindung herstellen
self.connection = sqlite3.connect(self.database)
self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
# Datenbank erstellen
self.cursor.execute(self.query)
```

Traceback:

```
    self.cursor.execute(self.query)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read the file contents, and pass it to [`cursor.executescript()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executescript) instead:

```
self.connection = sqlite3.connect(self.database)
self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
with open(self.query) as queryfile:
    self.cursor.executescript(queryfile.read())
```

Your error shows you were trying to execute the filename as a SQL statement; `cursor.execute()` can *only* handle actual SQL strings, not filenames.